# Submitting articles on arXiv as an unaffiliated researcher

Tags: phd, arxiv, affiliation

I was at a university for a year and then left. If I submit a research paper to arXiv and mention that I am a participant in that university, will they limit the research if it is accepted?
Because I have heard that arXiv does not accept unaffiliated research. (I have been endorsed on arXiv.)

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand some things. There is no prohibition against *unaffiliated* authors. You don't need to be associated with a university or research organization to submit. You do need to register, however, and you may need endorsements as well.

But affiliation, as such, is not a requirement.

There is also no concept of arXiv "limiting" your research. They make it public without review is all.

However, some publishers will reject work that has already appeared in any venue, including arXiv. That may be disappearing as I write, however. In some fields (math) the journals are very permissive. In others, not. The problem is that a commercial publisher wants to hold the copyright to the work, and by publishing it on arXiv you have already encumbered that copyright with the perpetual license you give them. So, the publisher, even if you assign copyright to them, needs to honor that license and can't claim "all rights reserved."

And, I hope you weren't dishonest about claiming affiliation with your former university. It isn't even needed.

ArXiv has a moderation process to weed out nonsense, but it has no proper review process. No one has necessarily verified the actual claims in any paper there. The endorsement process is just another way to weed out nonsense. Someone known to them, needs to vouch for you.